# JavaScript/Jquery or AJAX function to redirect a parent window html5 sandbox from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, frame, sandbox

I was using window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com"; previously to redirect a frame but since html5 it seems not to be working anymore.

I want to use my script  as frame but as mentioned before window.top.location.href isnt working anymore.

If some JS master knows an up to date solution it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is the iframe and the parent both on the same domain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Using the Location.replace method:

```
window.top.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
```

Option 2:
Using document object:

```
parent.document.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Option 3:
Using an anchor tag with `target` set to `"_top"`:

```
<a href="..." target="_top">link</a>
```

If my answer was helpful an upvote would be appreciated.